# Two way communication between a C++ program and an unidentified program

Tags: c++, communication

I would like to create a C++ program that can launch another program and communicate with it like a standard user.

Here is a basic example :
Say, I have program A in any kind of language (say Python for the exampe, but it sould be any kind of program). That program is launch via a console with a specific command (like "./myprogram.exe" or "python ./myprogram.py" or "java ./myprogram.jar"). It wait for the input of the user and give the sum of all the precedent inputs.

Example :

```
./myprogram.exe
Please enter a numer.
User > 4
4
User > 2
6
User > 9
15
```

So the program has a memory.

Now, what I want is automatize the user inputs and the output reading within a C++ program B. So my program B will automaticaly **send an input**, **wait for the other program A to give an output** before **sending another input** and so on... **Without closing and starting again program** A because program A has a memory of inputs.

Note : the program A (which is tested) is non changeable. I just want to benchmark it without modifying it.

Do you know how I can perform such communication ?

Thank you

Comment: What about sockets?

Comment: What do you want to benchmark ?

Comment: the usual solution for this is to execute program A from program B and redirect its input/output. In the unix world, you can do this with `pipe()`, `fork()`, `dup2()`, `read()` and `write()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your advices, but I read that `pipe()`, `fork()` and so on worked only in UNIX environment, and I work on Windows (sorry for forgetting to say that...).

So after searching a bit, finding documentations and creating some codes, I finally managed to get what I wanted.

**WARNING** : I give this solution for people who face the same problem as me and want the thing just to work. It may not be safe, it may not be the best solution, use this at your own risk. And remember that it is very specific to windows.

```
#include "iostream"

#include <windows.h> 
#include <tchar.h>
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <strsafe.h>

#define BUFSIZE 4096 

HANDLE g_hChildStd_IN_Rd = NULL;
HANDLE g_hChildStd_IN_Wr = NULL;
HANDLE g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd = NULL;
HANDLE g_hChildStd_OUT_Wr = NULL;

HANDLE g_hInputFile = NULL;

using namespace std;

void CreateChildProcess(string cmdLine);
void WriteToPipe(string input);
string ReadFromPipe();
void ErrorExit(PTSTR);


int main()
{
    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES saAttr;

    cout << "Starting pipes..." << endl;

    saAttr.nLength = sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES);
    saAttr.bInheritHandle = TRUE;
    saAttr.lpSecurityDescriptor = NULL;

    if (!CreatePipe(&g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd, &g_hChildStd_OUT_Wr, &saAttr, 0))
        cout << "Error : StdoutRd CreatePipe" << endl;

    if (!SetHandleInformation(g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0))
        cout << "Error : Stdout SetHandleInformation" << endl;

    if (!CreatePipe(&g_hChildStd_IN_Rd, &g_hChildStd_IN_Wr, &saAttr, 0))
        cout << "Error : Stdin CreatePipe" << endl;

    if (!SetHandleInformation(g_hChildStd_IN_Wr, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0))
        cout << "Error : Stdin SetHandleInformation" << endl;

    cout << "Creating child process..." << endl;

    CreateChildProcess("python C:/Users/Me/Desktop/Benchmark/test.py");

    WriteToPipe("5");

    ReadFromPipe();
    ReadFromPipe();

    getchar();

    return 0;
}

void CreateChildProcess(string cmdLine)
{   TCHAR *szCmdline = new TCHAR[cmdLine.size() + 1];
    szCmdline[cmdLine.size()] = 0;
    std::copy(cmdLine.begin(), cmdLine.end(), szCmdline);

    PROCESS_INFORMATION piProcInfo;
    STARTUPINFO siStartInfo;

    ZeroMemory(&piProcInfo, sizeof(PROCESS_INFORMATION));

    ZeroMemory(&siStartInfo, sizeof(STARTUPINFO));
    siStartInfo.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFO);
    siStartInfo.hStdError = g_hChildStd_OUT_Wr;
    siStartInfo.hStdOutput = g_hChildStd_OUT_Wr;
    siStartInfo.hStdInput = g_hChildStd_IN_Rd;
    siStartInfo.dwFlags |= STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;

    if (!CreateProcess(NULL, szCmdline, NULL, NULL, TRUE, 0, NULL, NULL, &siStartInfo, &piProcInfo))
    {
        cout << "Error : CreateProcess" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        CloseHandle(piProcInfo.hProcess);
        CloseHandle(piProcInfo.hThread);
    }
}

void WriteToPipe(string input)
{
    DWORD dwWritten;
    CHAR chBuf[BUFSIZE];

    cout << "> " << input.c_str() << endl;

    input += "\n";

    if (!WriteFile(g_hChildStd_IN_Wr, input.c_str(), strlen(input.c_str()), &dwWritten, NULL))
    {
        cout << "Error : WriteFile" << endl;
    }       
}

string ReadFromPipe()
{   
    DWORD dwRead, dwWritten;
    CHAR chBuf[BUFSIZE];
    BOOL bSuccess = FALSE;
    HANDLE hParentStdOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

    string output = "";
    bool flag = false;

    for (;;)
    {
        bSuccess = ReadFile(g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd, chBuf, BUFSIZE, &dwRead, NULL);
        if (!bSuccess || dwRead == 0) break;

        for (int i = 0; i < dwRead; i++)
        {
            if (chBuf[i] == '\n')
            {
                flag = true;
                break;
            }
            output += chBuf[i];
        }
        if (flag)
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    cout << "< " << output.c_str() << endl;

    return output;
}
```

And the program test.py is :

```
import sys

sys.stdout.write('Loading module\n')

test = int(input())

sys.stdout.write(str(test+1))
sys.stdout.write('\n')
```

What this will do is send the string "5\n" to test.py and read the output (which is "6"). It will work with any command like `java test.jar` or `python test.py` or just `test.exe`.

`void CreateChildProcess(string cmdLine)` allow you to create the child process with a specific command line.

`void WriteToPipe(string input)` allow you to send anything to the child process (a '\n' is automaticaly added)

`string ReadFromPipe()` is a synchronous function which output a line of the ouput of the child process (the last char '\n' is automaticaly deleted)

This solution is partially based on this well documented code : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682499(v=vs.85).aspx